# How can i find time-zone of all outlook meeting attendees?

Tags: outlook, timezone

In my application, i got a situation. I need to send email to all outlook meeting attendees and also have to specify the time at which meeting was scheduled. The problem is, every meeting attendee should get email with time specified in his own time-zone. **Question: Is there any way to find time zones of all meeting attendees ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

You don't have to worry about specifying the time according to the time-zone of the attendees. Outlook normalizes the time according to the System's local time of the recipient.

Please have a look at [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2642044) for more information on how the time is normalized.

So you can send the time of the meeting / appointment according to your local time and outlook automatically sets the meeting / appointment time to the recipient's time.

Please note: this auto normalization is for outlook 2010 and above. Will update the answer as soon as I find the information for other versions of outlook.

Hope this helps.

[UPDATE]
Link to how outlook handles multiple time-zones - [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195900)

Comment: The issue is I need to send **email** mentioning the time of meeting attendee's time-zone. Is there any way to find time zones for all meeting attendees at server side (from where i have to send email) ?

Comment: Is the email only to mention the time of the appointment? if so, instead of an email, why not create an appointment?

Comment: The scenario is, when someone will schedule a meeting for some future time, then 10 mins before meeting, we need to shoot an email saying, after 10 mins (@your time) you have a meeting so please review attached documents of this email. so we need to find the email recipient's time.

Comment: That's funny - 10 minutes should be 10 minutes regardless of time zone, unless dilatation effects are involved? I think the original question meant how can I find out whether the meeting that I schedule at a time convenient for me isn't in the middle of the night for my attendees?